# Full-text search using mysqli prepared statement errors with unmatched bind variables

Tags: php, full-text-search, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've written a simple search script in PHP. When run I get a blank screen and the PHP error log states

> Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement

I don't understand why it states this as there is one field I'm binding with - $searchTitle and one bind parameter stated (string). I may well have my markup completely wrong.

Any advice appreciated. Thanks.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btn-search-article'])) {
    $searchTitle = $_POST['search-title'];
    include_once("mysqli_connect.php");
    $table = "articles";  
    $sql = "SELECT title, 
            MATCH(title,category,artbody) 
            AGAINST ('?') 
            AS score
            FROM $table
            ORDER BY score DESC";                
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($dbh);
    if (!(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql))) {
        echo("Write to DB failed ");
    }
    else { //statement prepared ok
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $searchTitle);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $s1);
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
            echo($s1 . "<br>");
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
} else {
    echo("Error: Search could not be completed");
}
?>
```

NOTE: The PHP error log is stating that the error is on the line

> mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $s1);

FIXED: It seems the ordering of the sql statement was causing the error. Should be

```
$sql = "SELECT title
        FROM $table
        WHERE MATCH (title, category, artbody)
        AGAINST (?)";
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but did you try the statement without the quotes around the question mark?

Comment: Removes the quotes in `AGAINST ('?')`

Comment: Unfortunately removing the quotes didn't make any difference. Still producing the blank screen and error.

Comment: @tommyf, MySQLi has *terrible* error messages, and doesn't tell you if the query itself is wrong (e.g. wrong order, missing quotes, etc). So, whenever you see this error, after a quick check to see if the number of bind variables match up to the number of question marks in the query and number of characters in the `bind_param()` call, run the query against the database (e.g. via phpMyAdmin) as a normal query (replace `?` with actual text). That's typically the quickest way to debug these issues.

Comment: @bfrohs that's great advice. I didn't know about mysqli's poor error reporting. Thanks for the tip.